# make command error 13 on package creation

Tags: cisco, cisco-nso

I am working on sample nso package , while compiling it using `make` command facing bellow error:

```
     Must remake target `../load-dir/test-pack.fxs'.
Invoking recipe from Makefile:45 to update target `../load-dir/test-pack.fxs'.
/opt/ncs/ncs-5.6.8/bin/ncsc `ls test-pack-ann.yang  > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "-a test-pack-ann.yang"` --fail-on-warnings  -c -o ../load-dir/test-pack.fxs yang/test-pack.yang
Putting child 0x13caa40 (../load-dir/test-pack.fxs) PID 18182 on the chain.
Live child 0x13caa40 (../load-dir/test-pack.fxs) PID 18182
/opt/ncs/ncs-5.6.8/lib/ncs/erts/bin/ncsexec: Error 13 executing '/opt/ncs/ncs-5.6.8/lib/ncs/erts/bin/ncs.smp'.
Reaping losing child 0x13caa40 PID 18182
make: *** [../load-dir/test-pack.fxs] Error 1
Removing child 0x13caa40 PID 18182 from chain.
```

Can anyone suggest some pointers to resolve this please.

Thanks in advance.